# How to use GraphQL's Apollo client to store fetched data into Redux''s store

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo

How can one use GraphQL's Apollo client to store fetched data into Redux''s store?

The reason, why I cannot completely forego redux and completely rely on Apollo, is that I still need to use REST to fetch and store data from other places and store it into redux store, and redux store allows me to have extensions that are really useful in my application.

Using Apollo, it seems like I still need to rely on JSX, is there a way to bypass the JSX,  and  ? Or should I just rely on vanilla graphql queries?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use REST in apollo** - use redux for other global `app level state`.

It's discussable if data should be fetched using Redux these days. Refetching, polling, fetch more, subscriptions ... are doable in Redux but needs a lot of boilerplate and manual work.

ApolloClient of course can be used directly, w/o JSX.